# error when deserialize list to string when create new row blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, c#-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I work on asp.net core blazor i get error when deserialize list to string
so How to solve this issue please ?

error

```
 Error: System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ExpectedString(JsonTokenType tokenType)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetString()
```

error generationg on this statment below :

```
JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<string>(responsestream)
```

function that generate error is

```
private async Task CreateClick()
    {
        var deptobj = new ServerNamesClass() { server_Name = server_Name, server_Type = server_Type, operating_System = operating_System, version = version, isActive = isActive };
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, config["API_URL"] + "ServerNames");
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(deptobj), null, "application/json");
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        using var responsestream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        string res = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<string>(responsestream);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", res);
        await RefreshList();


    }
```

data returned on class below :

```
 public class ServerNamesClass
        {
            public int serverID { get; set; }
            public string server_Name { get; set; }
            public string server_Type { get; set; }
            public string operating_System { get; set; }
            public string version { get; set; }
            public bool isActive { get; set; }
        }
```

controller api

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddServer(ServerNames ServersName)
        {
            return Ok(_IserverNamesService.Insert(ServersName));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ReadFromJsonAsync instead of using ReadAsStreamAsync

Change your code:

```
using var responsestream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

to:

```
using var responsestream = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync();
```

or remove two lines of code and change it to new line:

```
using var responsestream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
string res = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<string>(responsestream);
```

to:

```
string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```